# PHP simple DOM parser confusion, help echo the tags: <div>content code</div>

Tags: php, dom

I'm confuse on what i'm working with. I'm trying to echo each open upto close tags for `<div>` to  `</div>` using Simple HTMl DOM parser. Using this example given from: (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm),  will just try to echo the text area inside the major div tags.

```
// Find all <div> which attribute id=foo
$ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');

// Find all <div> with the id attribute
$ret = $html->find('div[id]');
```

What if i want to echo including the `<div>` with and its id, the text or whatsoever code inside it and also echo the close tag `</div>` so that I will identify where the  code ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation for simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_access_special) for "How to access the HTML element's attributes?" on Tab "Magic attributes":

```
// Example
$html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>");
$e = $html->find("div", 0);

echo $e->tag; // Returns: " div"
echo $e->outertext; // Returns: " <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"
echo $e->innertext; // Returns: " foo <b>bar</b>"
echo $e->plaintext; // Returns: " foo bar"

Attribute Name  Usage
$e->tag            Read or write the tag name of element.
$e->outertext      Read or write the outer HTML text of element.
$e->innertext      Read or write the inner HTML text of element.
$e->plaintext      Read or write the plain text of element.
```

Comment: done editing the question, to clarify it, i want to echo the open <div> tag, its content/s, and also the close </div> tag.

Comment: @Stupefy How is `outertext` not doing that?

Comment: @Stupefy well, since it works and this is the only supplied answer, you are encouraged to mark this answer as the accepted answer by ticking the checkmark outline next to the answer (right below the voting controls). Thanks.